# Matlab imshow from vector

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, vector, imshow

I have a set of color images in a folder which I read into a matrix in the following manner:

```
dirOutput = dir(fullfile('\ImageExample\images','*.jpg'));
fileNames = {dirOutput.name};
for k=1:length(fileNames)
    cd '\ImageExample\images'
    H=fileNames{k};
    S=im2double(imresize(imread(H),[20 20]));
    T=S(:);
    data=[data;T'];
end
```

Here, each image has been converted to a row vector of the matrix data. Now I do a set of operations and want to plot back each of the rows of data back as an image of size 20X20X3(rgb) with the matrix elements as uint8. What set of commands would help me do so? After processing, I get a matrix of double data type.

Comment: `reshape`, `uint8`, `imshow`, `figure`, `help`, `image`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before we start, I would abolish storing each image as a single vector and use a `cell` array instead.  That way, you could just index the `cell` array and it would give you an output image as a result and escape that transformation from row vector to image.  However, my guess is that you're probably using some sort of minimization / machine learning framework where each image is a feature.

In any case, we are going to use the same `cell` array methodology here, and Divakar also pointed out what you should do.  You used the `(:)` operator to transform each resized colour image into a single vector.  To do the reverse operation, you need to use [`reshape`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html).  `reshape` takes in a 1D vector, and you specify the dimensions of the matrix you want and `reshape` will transform this 1D vector into the desired matrix of those desired dimensions.  Bear in mind that the dimensions you specify **must** satisfy the total number of elements in your 1D vector.

As such, to read back in your images, run a `for` loop through all of the rows in your image, extract each row vector, run `reshape`, and store this into a cell array.  You also need to use [`im2uint8`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/im2uint8.html) to convert the double image extracted per row, back into its original `uint8` form.  In other words:

```
numImages = size(data,1);
imageArray = cell(1,numImages);
for k = 1 : numImages
    T = data(k,:); %// Get row vector
    im = im2uint8(reshape(T, 20, 20, 3)); %// Reshape row vector into 20 x 20 x 3 matrix
    imageArray{k} = im;
end
```

---

If you want a one-liner solution (tip of the hat goes to Divakar), use [`arrayfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html) like so:

```
imageArray = arrayfun(@(x) im2uint8(reshape(data(x,:)), 20, 20, 3), 1:size(data,1), 'uni', 0);
```

---

Therefore, to access the k<sup>th</sup> image, simply do:

```
img = imageArray{k};
```

---

Good luck!

Comment: The issue occurs when i need to show the image using imshow, it is largely black, i tried multiplying the values by 255, but it makes it largely white. Is there any way to resolve this?